# Parse ASP.NET site niceties

Tags: asp.net, parsing, fiddler

I wrote many parsers (utilities that can call some site functions from windows UI) for many sites. This sites were wrote on PHP, Perl, Python,... And all works fine. But now I need write same utility for ASP.NET site. And I found a big problem.

When I try to repeate succesfull web session (I just use Fiddler->Composer and previous successfully web session data) I got error. Not error, but not same result as with success session. 
So I can login into site from browser (enter login and password and press button). But when I call **exactly same** POST request from Fiddler I got not logged user.

I found that all site based on one *form* (without action). Also there is __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT, __VIEWSTATE variables. First two are empty. Also much other variables. So site written into ASP.NET. 
Maybe I need some special nuance for working with ASP.NET sites? Or it just some programmers protection for just this one site? And what it can be?

Answer (score 1):

ViewState is dependent on state of previous pages shown so you need to recreate entire flow and resend the viewstate each time, try looking into how visual studio loadtesting component do it.

Comment: What do you mean "recreate entire flow"? Yes, I send VIEWSTATE and all other variables. I repeate exactly same succesfull web session (with all variables, cookies, headers...). And I tried login from different browsers under different logins but VIEWSTATE remain unchanged. /wEPDwULLTE0NzE4MzQ5MDBkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBSpjdGwwMCRIZWFkZXIxJGNudHJMb2dpbiRMb2dpblVzZXIkbG5rTG9naW4FKmN0bDAwJEhlYWRlcjEkY250ckxvZ2luJExvZ2luVXNlciRyZW1lbWJlcg== Mean -1471834900.

Comment: Try to run all request you collected in fiddler in order and see if you getting result you want